# Android layout/control to show "arrow" from opened Tab to List/Menu?

Tags: android, android-layout

I like the design of the Gmail app for android and I'm wondering if they created it using some standard approach.

I guess it uses fragments, one for the menu on the left side and another one for the content. But what looks really cool for me here is this little arrow pointing from the content to the selected item. It gives the feeling that the content page is placed on top of the rest.

Is something like this available out of the box?

[image]

Comment: Definitely not out of the box in the standard Android UI stack. Besides, the app looks suspiciously like HTML. Anyway, the triangle is not a part of the right pane - it's an dynamically visible element on the list item. As well as the broken border.

Answer (score 2):

I think they're using **android:windowContentOverlay** on the left side selected item where they show the "arrow"-like drawable. The drawable should have **android:gravity="right"** so it's placed correctly.

Of course, you would need to fine tune your layout to make it look "real", but I achieved some similar effects using this technique.

Comment: I'll add to the above that the drawable should also contain a shadow (if there is one in the middle, can't make it out of the screenshot), such that it will blend with the separator perfectly and seem like it's a continuation of it.

Comment: Supposing the left panel is a ListView, how to keep the selected item highlighted after it's released? I tried using selector but it only keeps it highlighted when you keep the item pressed.

Comment: I know. That doesn't work. What I did was have my item view (so a listview row) implement Checkable and then use ListView's setItemChecked(position, true) when I wanted to make an item behave differently. In your view you should change the view's background color/drawable to what you need. I also used a boolean mChecked member in my view, for easier state tracking. Pay attention to **always* call setItemChecked when you want the item to change state. Setting mChecked directly will cause your view to behave erratically because of item recycling.  Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like he is using 2 ListViews, and as far as that arrow I don't think it's available. I looked at a lot of 4.0 features but don't really see anything close to that. I'm thinking it could be part of the background for the right ListView?

Comment: Nah, must be one list view (left) and a custom view (right). It's too difficult to keep two list views in sync. I mean that it would be too difficult to position the arrow from the second list view.

Answer (score 0):

Multipane Layout: left side a list fragment (or fragment with a recyclerview), right side a fragment with the content view (scrollview, listview, recyclerview, webview, etc.).

If the item on the left is selected (single selection model), the selector uses a different drawable for the selected state and updates the content on the right. Maybe the listview item has a additional padding on the end to avoid overlap with the arrow bitmap drawable that is used within the selector.

On Lollipop there maybe also an additional ripple effect on top (draw selector on top or use a specific drawable-v21 with ripple).

The drop shadow effect can be achieved with a framelayout in the left fragment (first member is the listview, second member is a view that displays the shadow (gradient drawable) as background with gravity set to end).